# Adding a product to outpan via their api

Tags: outpan

I looked everywhere for a way to add a name, a barcode to outpan api.
I managed to get any product with barcode but to update name or add attribute it seems impossible.
they have provided a very limited documentation in their website https://www.outpan.com/developers

this particular one I am interested in I made every combination with the name still can't get it to work.
Here it is

**Add Product Name**

```
POST https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/[GTIN]/name?apikey=[YOUR API KEY]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Which programming language you are using?